# Ethernet cable works when plugged in directly, but not through modem

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem, switch

I have set up an ADSL modem/router as a switch, by forwarding the DHCP requests to my main router which also fulfills the role of a DHCP server.

I have achieved this by plugging in the ethernet cable for the main router in one of the LAN ports, and the ethernet cable to the computer in another one of the LAN ports.

This seems to work with my PC, and both wireless and ethernet seem to work, however when I try to plug the ethernet the same way into another PC, the ethernet cable doesn't seem to work (not connected, I checked ipconfig and also the cable does not light up.)

I know that the ethernet port seems to work as intended on both the PC and the modem/router, as a direct connection from the main router works with the PC, and the respective ethernet port on the router works on my main PC.

The LED for the ethernet slot that my other PC uses doesn't illuminate on the router either (however it does for my main PC and main router.)

I would like to know a potential cause for this, as I am clueless. I think one possibility is that the router is not supplying enough power to the ethernet cable, and the other PC needs a specific amount of power to function, but I assume that is unlikely.

Comment: Please explain in more detail exactly how everything is connected and what pieces of hardware are involved.

Comment: A schema of your local network will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up an ADSL modem/router as a switch, by forwarding the DHCP
> requests to my main router which also fulfills the role of a DHCP
> server.

I think this means you have set up the modem in Bridged Mode. I have my ISP modem set up this way.

You probably need to hook up LAN port 1 on the Modem to the WAN port of your router. The Router WAN port will have the external IP address of your system.

From here forward then, hook up everything to your Router and do not plug anything more into the modem. You likely only pay for 1 port and if you disconnect the Router and plug into that port, you will have to set up the external connection on the device you plug in. So just use the router on your own network. That will do all you need to do.